# Azure WebJob logging is crashing host, what can we do?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

We are using Azure to run several WebJobs. One of our WebJob functions has the following signature:

```
public static Task ProcessFileUploadedMessageAsync(
    [QueueTrigger("uploads")] FileUploadedMessage message,
    TextWriter logger,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

This function is monitoring a queue for a message that indicates a file has been uploaded, which then triggers an import of the file's data. Note the use of a `TextWriter` as the second argument: this is supplied by the WebJobs API infrastructure.

Our import process is kind of slow (can be several hours for a single file import in some cases), so we periodically write messages to the log (via the `TextWriter`) to track our progress. Unfortunately, our larger files are causing the WebJob hosting process to be terminated due to a logging exception. Here is a sample stack trace from the hosting process log:

```
[04/02/2016 03:44:59 > 660083: ERR ] 
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ] Parameter name: chunkLength
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at System.IO.StringWriter.ToString()
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Loggers.UpdateOutputLogCommand.<UpdateOutputBlob>d__10.MoveNext()
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Loggers.UpdateOutputLogCommand.<TryExecuteAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.RecurrentTaskSeriesCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.TaskSeriesTimer.<RunAsync>d__d.MoveNext()
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.BackgroundExceptionDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Throw>b__0()
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
[04/02/2016 03:45:00 > 660083: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766
[04/02/2016 03:45:01 > 660083: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 0 seconds
[04/02/2016 03:45:01 > 660083: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
```

The main problem is that this exception is being thrown not by our code but by something in the WebJobs API:

```
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Loggers.UpdateOutputLogCommand.<UpdateOutputBlob>d__10.MoveNext()
```

We tried putting `try...catch` blocks around our calls to the `TextWriter` but these had no effect. It would appear that log messages are buffered somewhere and periodically flushed to Azure blob storage by a separate thread. If this is the case, then it would follow that we have no way of trapping the exception.

**Has anyone else come across the same problem, or can anyone think of a possible solution or workaround?**

---

For completeness, here is how we are using the `TextWriter` for logging:

```
await logger.WriteLineAsync("some text to log");
```

Nothing more complicated than that.

---

**UPDATE**: Seems as though this has been reported as [issue #675 on the WebJobs SDK GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/675).

Comment: Steven, is it working without the async method : `logger.WriteLine("some text to log");` ?

Comment: @Thomas I haven't tried that

Answer (score 0):

You should add `async` to method, just like this:

```
public async static Task ProcessFileUploadedMessageAsync(...)
```

To get details, you can see [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/#trigger)

Comment: Thanks, but this particular method has no `await` calls in it and simply returns a Task generated by a different async method.

Comment: but you said you used 'await logger.WriteLineAsync("some text to log");' for logging. isn't this code in ProcessFileUploadedMessageAsync?

Comment: No, sorry, that was a simplification for the question. The logger isn't actually used in the WebJob method directly, it just gets passed through to the async method that returns a Task.